# TrueNAS LDAP Users not available in permissions dropdown

Tags: ldap, kerberos, nas

I have set up TrueNAS to use LDAP and Kerberos for authentication. The Directory Services Manager is showing the status of LDAP as Healthy and the users are listed when I type:

> getent passwd

However these same users are not available in the permissions dropdown for the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this. In the LDAP menu, there is an option to 'Rebuild Directory Services Cache'. Clicking this and waiting a minute will make the LDAP users available in the permissions dropdown.